# How to geocode address by google maps iOS API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

I found one way to send request:

> A Google Maps Geocoding API request takes the following form:
>
> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/outputFormat?parameters
>   where outputFormat may be either of the following values:
>
> json (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation
>   (JSON); or xml indicates output in XML To access the Google Maps
>   Geocoding API over HTTP, use:

But it's really inconvenient, is there any native way in swift?

I looked into GMSGeocoder interface and only reverse geocoding can be done by it's API.

Answer (score 22):

As others have pointed out, there is not a predefined method to do the search, but you can use network request to access the [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) yourself:

```
func performGoogleSearch(for string: String) {
    strings = nil
    tableView.reloadData()

    var components = URLComponents(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json")!
    let key = URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "...") // use your key
    let address = URLQueryItem(name: "address", value: string)
    components.queryItems = [key, address]

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: components.url!) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200, error == nil else {
            print(String(describing: response))
            print(String(describing: error))
            return
        }

        guard let json = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)) as? [String: Any] else {
            print("not JSON format expected")
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "Not string?!?")
            return
        }

        guard let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
            let status = json["status"] as? String,
            status == "OK" else {
                print("no results")
                print(String(describing: json))
                return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // now do something with the results, e.g. grab `formatted_address`:
            let strings = results.compactMap { $0["formatted_address"] as? String }
            ...
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Strangely I get the error *This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address xxx.xx.xx.xx, with empty referer* even though I have enabled the API and restricted it with my app's bundle identifier.

Comment: Update: Found the fix. Apparently I had to pass the bundle identifier as a header value _X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier_ in this request. That's when it worked.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no native way in the Google Maps SDK for iOS.

This is a very popular feature request though, see:
[Issue 5170: Feature request: Forward geocoding (from address to coordinates)](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5170)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that as native. I hope that function will help.

```
    func getAddress(address:String){

    let key : String = "YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY"
    let postParameters:[String: Any] = [ "address": address,"key":key]
    let url : String = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: postParameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON {  response in

        if let receivedResults = response.result.value
        {
            let resultParams = JSON(receivedResults)
            print(resultParams) // RESULT JSON
            print(resultParams["status"]) // OK, ERROR
            print(resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"].doubleValue) // approximately latitude
            print(resultParams["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"].doubleValue) // approximately longitude
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Alamofire and [Google's Geodecode API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

**Swift 4**

```
func getAddressFromLatLong(latitude: Double, longitude : Double) {
    let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=\(latitude),\(longitude)&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"

    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:

            let responseJson = response.result.value! as! NSDictionary

            if let results = responseJson.object(forKey: "results")! as? [NSDictionary] {
                if results.count > 0 {
                    if let addressComponents = results[0]["address_components"]! as? [NSDictionary] {
                        self.address = results[0]["formatted_address"] as? String
                        for component in addressComponents {
                            if let temp = component.object(forKey: "types") as? [String] {
                                if (temp[0] == "postal_code") {
                                    self.pincode = component["long_name"] as? String
                                }
                                if (temp[0] == "locality") {
                                    self.city = component["long_name"] as? String
                                }
                                if (temp[0] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                    self.state = component["long_name"] as? String
                                }
                                if (temp[0] == "country") {
                                    self.country = component["long_name"] as? String
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a Geocoding solution you could look into a little open source project I built. It is very lightweight and uses OpenStreetMap's geocoding API called Nominatim. Check it out here: https://github.com/caloon/NominatimSwift

You can even search for landmarks.

Geocoding addresses and landmarks:

```
Nominatim.getLocation(fromAddress: "The Royal Palace of Stockholm", completion: {(error, location) -> Void in
  print("Geolocation of the Royal Palace of Stockholm:")
  print("lat = " + (location?.latitude)! + "   lon = " + (location?.longitude)!)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send a request through URL session of the address using [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) of Google Places API and then parse the json result. It may not be perfect but you can get more information other than coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native way in the Google Maps API iOS SDK. As has been mentioned in other answers, it's been a [requested feature for years](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5170).

One thing to remember is that Google Maps APIs are mostly focused on creating maps: that's a primary goal.

You have to use the URL-based API calls or some other service. For instance, a different service called SmartyStreets has an iOS SDK that has native support for forward geocoding. Here's the example code for Swift from [their iOS SDK documentation page](https://smartystreets.com/docs/sdk/ios):

```
// Swift: Sending a Single Lookup to the US ZIP Code API

package examples;

import Foundation
import SmartystreetsSDK

class ZipCodeSingleLookupExample {

    func run() -> String {
        let mobile = SSSharedCredentials(id: "SMARTY WEBSITE KEY HERE", hostname: "HOST HERE")
        let client = SSZipCodeClientBuilder(signer: mobile).build()
//        Uncomment the following line to use Static Credentials
//        let client = SSZipCodeClientBuilder(authId: "YOUR AUTH-ID HERE", authToken: "YOUR AUTH-TOKEN HERE").build()

        let lookup = SSZipCodeLookup()
        lookup.city = "Mountain View"
        lookup.state = "California"

        do {
            try client?.send(lookup)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(String(format: "Domain: %@", error.domain))
            print(String(format: "Error Code: %i", error.code))
            print(String(format: "Description: %@", error.localizedDescription))
            return "Error sending request"
        }

        let result: SSResult = lookup.result
        let zipCodes = result.zipCodes
        let cities = result.cities

        var output: String = String()

        if (cities == nil && zipCodes == nil) {
            output += "Error getting cities and zip codes."
            return output
        }

        for city in cities! {
            output += "\nCity: " + (city as! SSCity).city
            output += "\nState: " + (city as! SSCity).state
            output += "\nMailable City: " + ((city as! SSCity).mailableCity ? "YES" : "NO") + "\n"
        }

        for zip in zipCodes! {
            output += "\nZIP Code: " + (zip as! SSZipCode).zipCode
            output += "\nLatitude: " + String(format:"%f", (zip as! SSZipCode).latitude)
            output += "\nLongitude: " + String(format:"%f", (zip as! SSZipCode).longitude) + "\n"
        }

        return output
    }
}
```

Full disclosure: I have worked for SmartyStreets.